# Quick sort throws a 'not in inclusive range' error but sometimes it works. (Dart)

Tags: dart, data-structures, quicksort

I have implemented a quick sort algorithm in Dart which sorts a list of random integers in the range from 0 to 100. Most of the times, it throws a 'not in inclusive range' exception. Other times, it works. I don't understand what is wrong with my code or logic here.

```
import 'dart:math';

List<int> list = [];

void main() {
  randomize();
  quickSort(0, list.length - 1);
  print(list);
}

void randomize() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    list.add(Random().nextInt(100));
  }
}

void quickSort(int l, int h) {
  if (l < h) {
    int mid = partition(l, h);
    quickSort(l, mid - 1);
    quickSort(mid + 1, h);
  }
}

int partition(int l, int h) {
  int pivot = l;
  int i = l;
  int j = h;

  while (i < j) {
    while (list[i] <= list[pivot]) {
      ++i;
    }
    while (list[j] > list[pivot]) {
      --j;
    }
    if (i < j) {
      int temp = list[i];
      list[i] = list[j];
      list[j] = temp;
    }
  }
  int temp = list[pivot];
  list[pivot] = list[j];
  list[j] = temp;

  return j;
}
```

Comment: What prevents `++i` from going out of bounds?  To help yourself debug it, you also should print `list` *first*.  That will you give a reproducible failure case, and then you can use that to step through your code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Oh okay I think I'm getting you're hinting at. What if the 'i' variable never found an element greater than the pivot. It will run out of bounds. I think it should be something along the lines of 'i < h' and 'j > l'.
Thanks @jamesdlin, you're a life saver!

Comment: The code is using Lomuto type calls `mid - 1`, `mid+1`, but the partition function is similar to Hoare. I recommend using the logic from the [Wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) .